# Cannot see Selenium logs

Tags: selenium-rc

I am not able see Selenium LOGs files by clicking the `Show log` button present in the Selenium rc window after each time my scripts run. Are any settings needed to show the log?

Answer (score 0):

The log window often appears off-screen for me, probably because I have multiple monitors.  I get it into view by right-clicking on the window name on the taskbar, selecting "Move" from the context menu, and then using the arrow keys to move it into view.  Once it's partly in view, I can drag it anywhere I want using the mouse.